# HelloCharts Produces Null Object Reference When Trying to View In AlertDialog

Tags: javascript, android, charts

I am trying use HelloCharts to produce a pie chart in an AlertDialog. I have been able to successfully produce a chart in a separate application, however when I move the code to my main application and place in the AlertDialog I get the following error:

```
08-21 17:59:28.218 10363-10363/ca.rvogl.tpbcui E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ca.rvogl.tpbcui, PID: 10363
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.PieChartView.setPieChartData(lecho.lib.hellocharts.model.PieChartData)' on a null object reference
    at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.views.SeriesActivity.showSeriesDetailsDialog(SeriesActivity.java:309)
    at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.views.SeriesActivity.access$300(SeriesActivity.java:43)
    at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.views.SeriesActivity$4.onClick(SeriesActivity.java:252)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1067)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1156)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3121)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4036)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I have tried searching through stackoverflow, as well as google searches for any reference to this, but could find nothing.  Maybe someone here can provide me with some insight on this.  Below is my alertdialog code and the xml layout for reference.

```
//Show Alert Dialog With Pie Chart Displaying Stats
    private void showSeriesDetailsDialog( final Series series, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        final View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dialog_seriesdetails, null);

        //AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(SeriesActivity.this);
        //alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(view);

        PieChartView pieChartView = findViewById(R.id.chart);
        List<SliceValue> pieData = new ArrayList<>();

        Integer strikes = 9;
        Integer spares = 1;
        Integer splits = 1;
        Integer splitconversion = 1;
        Integer openframes = 0;

        if (strikes < 1) {
        } else {
            pieData.add(new SliceValue(strikes, Color.parseColor("#33B5E5")).setLabel(strikes +" Strikes" ));
        }
        if (spares < 1) {
        } else {
            pieData.add(new SliceValue(spares, Color.parseColor("#99CC00")).setLabel(spares +" Spares"));
        }
        if (splits < 1) {
        } else { pieData.add(new SliceValue(splits, Color.parseColor("#FF4444")).setLabel(splits +" Split"));
        }
        if (splitconversion < 1) {
        } else {
            pieData.add(new SliceValue(splitconversion, Color.parseColor("#AA66CC")).setLabel(splitconversion +" Split Conversion "));
        }
        if (openframes < 1) {
        } else {
            pieData.add(new SliceValue(openframes, Color.parseColor("#ff6f60")).setLabel(openframes +" Open Frames "));
        }


        PieChartData pieChartData = new PieChartData(pieData);
        pieChartData.setHasLabels(true).setValueLabelTextSize(8);
        pieChartData.setValueLabelBackgroundEnabled(false);
        pieChartData.setHasCenterCircle(true).setCenterText1("Series Stats").setCenterText1FontSize(18).setCenterText1Color(Color.parseColor("#0097A7"));;
        pieChartView.setPieChartData(pieChartData);

       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

xml Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="24dp" >

    <lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.PieChartView
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose the PieChartView belongs to the inflated layout dialog_seriesdetails.xml? Then you have to "find" it in the inflated `View` not in the `Activity`'s content View (and that's where `Activity.findViewById()` is going to look). So you need to write `PieChartView pieChartView = view.findViewyId(...);`

Comment: I am not sure that I follow you.  Can you provide a sample of what you are referring to?

Comment: Well, I can try to explain some more (this means I will try to really "answer" your question) but am I correct that the xml file you shared in your question is the one called  dialog_seriesdetails.xml which you inflate in your method showSeriesDetailsDialog()? (It might be the Activity layout after all)

Comment: Yes dialog_seriesdetails.xml is what I am trying to inflate inside showSeriesDetails().  See screen shot above

Comment: can you post your activitys onCreate?

Comment: I could, but I prefer to have the chart appear in the dialog if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line you inflate the `View` for the `AlertDialog` from  *dialog_seriesdetails.xml*

```
final View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dialog_seriesdetails, null);
```

The `PieChartView` is part of that layout. If you want to assign it to some variable, you need to write

```
PieChartView pieChartView =  view.findViewById(R.idchart);
```

The method `View.findViewById(int)` returns the first `View` with the desired id which can be found in the entire `View` hierarchy of the `View` on which it is called, so it is not limited to finding direct children. (But if you use it on a `ListView` and pass in the id of some `View` which is present in each row then you can't be sure what it will return)

But why did you get the `NullPointerException`? Your code

```
 PieChartView pieChartView =  findViewById(R.idchart);
```

did not use `View.findViewById()` but `Activity.findViewById()`. The `Activity` method works just like the `View` method but it searches in the layout which you pass in `setContentView()` (usually the first thing you do in `onCreate()` )

There is no `View` with id *chart* in the `Activity` layout so *pieChartView* was `null`.

Comment: @Robert Vogl - one other thing: once you make it past the line with the NPE you will notice that the chart does not show in the AlertDialog. You need to write something like [alertDialog.setView(view);](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder#setView(int)) before calling show()

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying.  But I am using **PieChartView pieChartView = findViewById(R.id.chart);** after I specify the xml layout that contains the chart.  How would I go about fixing this? I seem to be having server mental block.  lol 1 to many times banging my head against the keyboard in frustration.

Comment: @RobertVogl - You need to add **"view."** before "findViewByIdR.id.chart);" and after "pieChartView = "

Comment: OMG!! I feel like such an idiot.  Makes total sense now.  pieChartView gets associated to the view I created to inflate the xml layout. **doh!**  I guess I can go put some ice on my head now.  Thank you so much for pointing this out to me.   Seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

```
PieChartView pieChartView = (PieChartView) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

Comment: Cast with PieChartView and View.findViewById is a must when you use Fragment, it's different than Activity

Comment: I have already tried this and it produces the exact same results as the logcat above and besides I am not using Fragments, this is an Activity.

Comment: Now that I have had the ah ha moment.  I see that you were trying to tell me to add the view to the findView as well.   My apologies.